# "Take Ownership" drop-down menu option

Tags: windows-7, windows

What does "Take Ownership" on drop-down menus for folders / documents / etc mean?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "drop-down" you mean the [Context Menu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_menu) (right-click), then that option being there is not standard to Windows.

It can be added via registry edits -- see [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) and [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html) for example.

A nice, concise blurb from Microsoft about what file ownership is can be found in [Take Ownership of a File or Folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659.aspx):

> The owner of the object controls how permissions are set on the object and to whom permissions are granted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a built-in feature. Seems like someone manually installed it on your Windows from, for example, here: [Windows 7 - Take Ownership Shortcut](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1911-take-ownership-shortcut.html)