# How can I delete .FON files on a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I want to remove two .FON files (not in the "Fonts" folder), but got this error:

[image]

Apparently just copying a file is enough to be hogged by Windows.
(This is my pet peeve with Windows: it does a lot of things the guys in Redmond find clever, but only make your life harder.)

I tried *Unlocker* but it didn't find a locking handle.

How can I delete .FON files?

---

PS: please no advices to switch to Linux or Mac.

Comment: I do not know, A windows destruct/control kit starts with full system backup,  then unlocker and then "take ownership" http://superuser.com/questions/557714/take-ownership-drop-down-menu-option?s=3|3.1557 Which addresses permissions easily , usually needed for trusted installer. Then continues with a HardLink extention, to see additional links   A side order of the RunAsSystem thrown in and you can do anything.  But this font is not default?  it is not showing up here?   It really isn't that clever, there are  misteaks you can make when taking back control, that make things far worse, Backup.

Comment: No, it's not a default font. It's just a file that happens to be so unlucky to have a .FON extension. It's not even on the system partition!

Comment: So how did it come into being? just the existance of a .fon extention does not seem to mean anything when tested here.  Who/what has permissions for it now?  The web indicates that some malware has applied that extention to hide (but what ext would they not use :-)   Some unruely files can be removed easily in safe mode, or via a different system..

Comment: @stevenvh: Do you have the Preview pane open in Windows Explorer and any of these .FON files selected? Have you tried closing all instances of Explorer (including via Ctrl+Shift+right click on Start Menu) and deleting the files using the cmd prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Those are AsynchPro VT100 terminal emulator fonts. Either AsnchPro installed them, or Windows just found them somehow.

As you know of course, installation puts either the Font file, or a shortcut to the Font File, in the Windows Font folder. The actual files may be anywhere on your PC.

Anyway, installed or not, on the security tab of those files, give "SYSTEM" all "deny" privileges. This prevents the system from loading the file. Then delete them.

You can probably achieve the same effect by booting in Safe Mode.